# DOMDocument with php

Tags: php, domdocument

> i want replace all images on my html but the code replace one and escaping one and so on

i use DOMDocument to replace images on my content and i use the next code  the problem is the code escaping image 
for example

> 1 2 3 4 images the code replace one and three and escaping tow and four and so on

[image: see the result on action]

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML("data"));
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $count = 1;

    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($images as $img) {

        $src =   $img->getAttribute('src');
        $newsrc = $dom->createElement("newimg");
        $newsrc->nodeValue = $src;
        $newsrc->setAttribute("id","qw".$count);
        $img->parentNode->replaceChild($newsrc, $img);
        $count++;

    }

    $html = $dom->saveHTML();
    return $html;
```

the html code is

```
 <p><img class="img-responsive"  src="http://www.jarofquotes.com/img/quotes/86444b28aa86d706e33246b823045270.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="455" /></p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p>some text</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p><img class="img-responsive" src="http://40.media.tumblr.com/c0bc20fd255cc18dca150640a25e13ef/tumblr_nammr75ACv1taqt2oo1_500.jpg" alt="" width="480" height="477" /></p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p><span class="marker"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://wiselygreen.com/wp-content/uploads/green-living-coach-icon.png" alt="" width="250" height="250" /><br /><br /></span></p>
```

i want output html replace all images with

```
   <newimg>Src </newimg>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the exact problem in your question?

Comment: the code you show creates an element names "newimg". that's not a valid html element. can you show a snippet of the input html and the desired output html? Your image and description doesn't help me understand the issue.

Comment: @Gordon
 i want output html replace ALL images with

       <newimg>Src </newimg>
the code escaping one after one

Comment: aaah, now I get what you mean. That's because NodeLists are live lists. Let me fetch the duplicate.

Comment: @Gordon Ok waiting for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I couldn't find a dupe suitable for PHP, so I am answering this one.

The issue you are facing is that NodeLists returned by `getElementsByTagName()` are live list. That means, when you do the call to `replaceChild()`, you are altering the NodeList you are currently iterating.

Let's assume we have this HTML:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="1.jpg"/>
        <img src="2.jpg"/>
        <img src="3.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;
```

Now let's load it into a `DOMDocument` and get the `img` elements:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$allImages = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
echo $allImages->length, PHP_EOL;
```

This will print 3 because there is 3 `img` elements in the DOM right now.

Let's replace the first `img` element with a `p` element:

```
$allImages->item(0)->parentNode->replaceChild(
    $dom->createElement("p"),
    $allImages->item(0)
);
echo $allImages->length, PHP_EOL;
```

This now gives 2 because there is now only 2 `img` elements left, essentially

```
item 0: img will be removed from the list
item 1: img will become item 0
item 2: img will become item 1
```

You are using `foreach`, so you are first replacing item 0, then move on to item 1, but item 1 is now item 2 and the item 0 is item 1 you would expect next. But because the list is live, you are skipping it.

To get around this, use a `while` loop and always replace the first element:

```
while ($allImages->length > 0) {
    $allImages->item(0)->parentNode->replaceChild(
        $dom->createElement("p"),
        $allImages->item(0)
    );
}
```

This will then catch all the `img` elements.

Comment: working like a charm you saved my day and nice explanation thanks man